# com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: unauthorized

Tags: java, android, android-studio, parse-platform, back4app

I am new in android. Well I am trying to send data to parse cloud, but I am getting this exception.

```
com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: unauthorized
```

**Here is the MainActivity class.**

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2015-present, Parse, LLC.
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the BSD-style license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree. An additional grant
 * of patent rights can be found in the PATENTS file in the same directory.
 */
package com.parse.starter;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.parse.ParseAnalytics;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.SaveCallback;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      ParseObject score = new ParseObject("Score");
      score.put("username","azeem");
      score.put("score","199");
      score.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
          @Override
          public void done(ParseException e) {
              if (e == null)
              {
                  Log.i("SaveInBackground","Succesfully");
              }
              else {
                  Log.i("SaveInBackground","Failed");
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
          }
      });

      ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(getIntent());

  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
      return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
}
```

And here is the logcat.

```
08-02 16:03:14.278 2542-2542/com.parse.starter I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
08-02 16:03:14.356 2542-2542/com.parse.starter W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.parse.starter-2/lib/x86
08-02 16:03:20.832 2542-2542/com.parse.starter W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.parse.starter-2/lib/x86
08-02 16:03:21.431 2542-2548/com.parse.starter W/art: Suspending all threads took: 80.123ms
08-02 16:03:22.473 2542-2548/com.parse.starter W/art: Suspending all threads took: 120.266ms
08-02 16:03:22.642 2542-2552/com.parse.starter I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 16012(1690KB) AllocSpace objects, 8(164KB) LOS objects, 69% free, 1121KB/3MB, paused 823us total 115.234ms
08-02 16:03:25.669 2542-2548/com.parse.starter W/art: Suspending all threads took: 2.314s
08-02 16:03:26.291 2542-2548/com.parse.starter W/art: Suspending all threads took: 431.859ms
08-02 16:03:26.369 2542-2548/com.parse.starter W/art: Suspending all threads took: 9.786ms
08-02 16:03:26.814 2542-2992/com.parse.starter D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true

                                                                 [ 08-02 16:03:26.823  2542: 2542 D/         ]
                                                                 HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaa1a8560, tid 2542
08-02 16:03:26.875 2542-2548/com.parse.starter W/art: Suspending all threads took: 14.603ms
08-02 16:03:26.899 2542-2992/com.parse.starter I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
08-02 16:03:27.395 2542-2548/com.parse.starter W/art: Suspending all threads took: 34.582ms
08-02 16:03:28.902 2542-2548/com.parse.starter W/art: Suspending all threads took: 536.386ms
08-02 16:19:43.659 2542-2548/com.parse.starter W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.097ms
08-02 16:19:48.994 2542-2883/com.parse.starter W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/data/com.parse.starter/lib
08-02 16:19:49.119 2542-2992/com.parse.starter E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa9a52620
08-02 16:19:49.313 2542-2992/com.parse.starter V/RenderScript: 0xa0f87000 Launching thread(s), CPUs 2
08-02 16:19:51.063 2542-2992/com.parse.starter E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa9a52690
08-02 16:19:54.880 2542-2542/com.parse.starter W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.internal.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
08-02 16:19:56.241 2542-2992/com.parse.starter E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa9a52690
08-02 16:20:43.221 2542-2883/com.parse.starter W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/data/com.parse.starter/lib
08-02 16:20:43.259 2542-2992/com.parse.starter E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa9a52620
08-02 16:20:45.238 2542-2992/com.parse.starter E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa9a52620
08-02 16:25:09.700 2542-2992/com.parse.starter E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa9a52ee0
08-02 16:57:48.310 2542-2992/com.parse.starter E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa9a525b0
08-02 16:58:45.961 18271-18271/com.parse.starter W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.parse.starter-1/lib/x86
08-02 16:58:53.160 18271-18271/com.parse.starter W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.parse.starter-1/lib/x86
08-02 16:58:53.427 18271-18531/com.parse.starter D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true

                                                                   [ 08-02 16:58:53.431 18271:18271 D/         ]
                                                                   HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaa1a87d0, tid 18271


                                                                   [ 08-02 16:58:53.496 18271:18531 D/         ]
                                                                   HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xadc47ba0, tid 18531
08-02 16:58:53.501 18271-18531/com.parse.starter I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
08-02 17:09:48.803 20084-20084/com.parse.starter W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.parse.starter-2/lib/x86
08-02 17:09:53.513 20084-20084/com.parse.starter W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.parse.starter-2/lib/x86
08-02 17:09:53.870 20084-20192/com.parse.starter D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true

                                                                   [ 08-02 17:09:53.875 20084:20084 D/         ]
                                                                   HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaa1a76f0, tid 20084


                                                                   [ 08-02 17:09:53.913 20084:20192 D/         ]
                                                                   HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xadc47b70, tid 20192
08-02 17:09:53.917 20084-20192/com.parse.starter I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
08-02 17:15:47.485 25321-25321/com.parse.starter W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.parse.starter-2/lib/x86
08-02 17:15:49.386 25321-25321/com.parse.starter W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.parse.starter-2/lib/x86
08-02 17:15:49.730 25321-25384/com.parse.starter D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true

                                                                   [ 08-02 17:15:49.733 25321:25321 D/         ]
                                                                   HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaa1a9010, tid 25321


                                                                   [ 08-02 17:15:49.763 25321:25384 D/         ]
                                                                   HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaa1a8e60, tid 25384
08-02 17:15:49.769 25321-25384/com.parse.starter I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
08-02 17:16:16.054 25321-25321/com.parse.starter I/SaveInBackground: Failed
08-02 17:16:16.055 25321-25321/com.parse.starter W/System.err: com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: unauthorized
08-02 17:16:16.055 25321-25321/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at com.parse.ParseRequest.newPermanentException(ParseRequest.java:270)
08-02 17:16:16.055 25321-25321/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at com.parse.ParseRESTCommand.onResponseAsync(ParseRESTCommand.java:301)
08-02 17:16:16.055 25321-25321/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at com.parse.ParseRESTUserCommand.onResponseAsync(ParseRESTUserCommand.java:126)
08-02 17:16:16.055 25321-25321/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at com.parse.ParseRequest$3.then(ParseRequest.java:137)
08-02 17:16:16.055 25321-25321/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at com.parse.ParseRequest$3.then(ParseRequest.java:133)
08-02 17:16:16.055 25321-25321/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at bolts.Task$15.run(Task.java:917)
08-02 17:16:16.055 25321-25321/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:105)
08-02 17:16:16.055 25321-25321/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:908)
08-02 17:16:16.055 25321-25321/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:715)
08-02 17:16:16.055 25321-25321/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:726)
08-02 17:16:16.055 25321-25321/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at bolts.Task$13.then(Task.java:818)
08-02 17:16:16.055 25321-25321/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at bolts.Task$13.then(Task.java:806)
08-02 17:16:16.055 25321-25321/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at bolts.Task$15.run(Task.java:917)
08-02 17:16:16.055 25321-25321/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
08-02 17:16:16.055 25321-25321/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
08-02 17:16:16.055 25321-25321/com.parse.starter W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Well I am using https://www.back4app.com/ because parse.com going to shutdown soon.

Comment: did you initialize the parse SDK? if yes can you please paste the code where you initialize it?

Comment: what do you mean by initialize? 
I just import sdk by importing existing project.
And add app-id and client id.
And then add some code to MainActivity class in onCreate method.

Comment: Before you are start to run queries or do any interaction with parse SDK you need to initialize it and send your app is and client key

Comment: How should I do that? I have insert app-id and client key into string.xml file.

Comment: @HaiderAkbar just a note, I recommend Firebase

Comment: Ok. I will write an answer on the steps that needs to be done in order to do it. @AbAppletic - why firebase? if someone already created something with parse why he need to go with firebase? you can have firebase in parallel if you really need but there are a lot of things in parse that firebase not provide

Comment: @RanHassid chill, just a suggestion as Firebase was announced as Google's official database...

Comment: @AbAppletic i am ok with that but when you recommend something you should provide a reason why.. I know that firebase is very powerful especially after they were acquired by google. I used them one for video chat and for other real time stuff :)

Answer (score 2):

Usually the reason you get UnAuthorized is because you didn't initiate the parse SDK or you didn't send the correct APP_ID and/or CLIENT_KEY
in order to do it please do the following:

1. Initiate Parse SDK by using the following code

   ```
   Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
           .applicationId("{YOUR_APP_ID}")
           .server("{YOUR_ENDPOINT_URL}")
           .clientKey("{YOUR_CLIENT_KEY}")
           .build());
   ```
2. After initiate the Parse SDK you can either signup/login a user by using

   ```
   ParseUser.logInInBackground("{USER}", "{PASSWORD}", new LogInCallback() {
       @Override
       public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {

       }
   });
   ```

   or signing up using the following code:

   ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
       user.setEmail("{EMAIL}");
       user.setUsername("{USERNAME}");
       user.setPassword("{PASSWORD}");
       user.put("firstName","{FIRST_NAME}");
       // add more properties here

   ```
   user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
       @Override
       public void done(ParseException e) {

       }
   });
   ```
3. After that you validate that all the details are ok you can continue and query,create,update or delete parse objects

Good luck :)

Comment: thank you so much. But can you tell me where to get endpoint url?
And where to paste that code?

Comment: End point URL is your REST API URL so in your case if is in on your local host it will be http://localhost:1337/parse and if is deployed then it will be you http://{deploy_url}:1337/parse the 1337 is the default port so if you change it to another just make sure that you also change it. In the client side

Answer (score 1):

Parse provide many plan for developer for hosting, Free plan user has some limitation to storage,access and request. In my case i got this error due to complete my all the "**request/month**".

For free plan user can have **10k request per month**. After that you have to upgrade plan other wise they will block your permission.

I attached screen shot , you can find it from billing section from your parse app.

[image]